# Packaging common function arguments into struct - reducing repetition, fighting borrow checker

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm working on a small application where I found myself passing many of the same `&mut` arguments to functions over and over. Example:

```
fn xyz(a: &mut A, b: &mut B) { /* ... */ }
fn bar(a: &mut A, b: &mut B, c: &mut C) { xyz(a, b); /* ... */ }
fn foo(a: &mut A, b: &mut B, c: &mut C) { bar(a, b, c); /* ... */ }
```

While in my real world case the functions slightly varied in arity between each other, there were always 3-4 arguments in common. I decided to do something that I thought was sensible: wrap the common arguments in a `struct` and pass the `struct` instead.

```
struct Context {
    a: A, 
    b: B, 
    c: C
}

fn xyz(c: &mut Context) { /* ... */ }
fn bar(c: &mut Context) { xyz(c); /* ... */ }
fn foo(c: &mut Context) { bar(c); /* ... */ }
```

---

If a function only needs a subset of `Context`'s arguments and if the call depends on one of them, the borrow checker complains. Here's an example:

```
struct Context {
    f0: HashSet<String>,
    f1: HashSet<String>,
}

fn bar(f1: &mut HashSet<String>) {}

fn foo(k: &str, c: &mut Context) {
    c.f0.get(k).map(|_| bar(&mut c.f1));
}
```

```
error[E0500]: closure requires unique access to `c` but `c.f0` is already borrowed
  --> <anon>:11:21
   |
11 |     c.f0.get(k).map(|_| bar(&mut c.f1));
   |     ----            ^^^          -    - borrow ends here
   |     |               |            |
   |     |               |            borrow occurs due to use of `c` in closure
   |     |               closure construction occurs here
   |     borrow occurs here
```

[**on rust playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8b03525f8a46439208d50ab121a401e2&version=stable&backtrace=0)

---

I understand why the error is happening, but I would like to avoid all the code repetition that happens when passing arguments individually. Note that passing arguments individually does prevent the issue:

```
fn bar(f1: &mut HashSet<String>) {}

fn foo(k: &str, f0: &mut HashSet<String>, f1: &mut HashSet<String>) {
    f0.get(k).map(|_| bar(f1));
}
```

[**on rust playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d97e1c0db35547320ac3b5fe15f783e2&version=stable&backtrace=0)

While not true for this minimal example, using something like `Context` increased the readability of my real code significantly, as the function signatures were shorter and code repetition was diminished.

---

**Is there a way to reduce code repetition when multiple functions share a subset of arguments?**

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=66ba6046049adf4589f975dc646c2878&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: @Stargateur: thanks. What if `bar` accepted a `Context` though? Is accepting separate arguments the only way to make it work?

Comment: Sorry I can't answer you, because I don't fully understand what you ask and I probably don't have the knowledge to answer this. Maybe you can go on the [rust chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust). To ask this to experimented user. I'm still learning rust.